# Find closest date before other date and look up the value

Tags: excel, date, time, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two different files.

1. File is with date and information what i need.
   Like this:

[image]

In A and B i have date and time in C the information that i need to look up based by other file date.

2. File

[image]

What I need:

1. To find closest date and time from file NR. 1 (A and B cells) before that date that are in File NR.2 (B and C cells)
2. Return value from file Nr. 1 C cell to file NR. 2 in F cell

I try a lot of formulas and none of them working..

Any ideas?

INDEX/MATCH formula: in File NR.2 F2 cell

```
=INDEX('[kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx]Single'!$A:$A;
       MATCH(MIN(ABS('[kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx]Single'!$A:$A-B2));
             ABS('[kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx]Single'!$A:$A-B2);0)
      )
```

Returns #N/A

Comment: Sounds like `INDEX/MATCH` would do the job. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52970453/edit) and let us know what you've tried?

Comment: Just for clarification, if you have `2018.09.19 14:05` in NR.2 and the two values `2018.09.19 10:30` and `2018.09.19 14:45` in NR.1, you want the formula to return the Stamping Date associated with `2018.09.19 10:30`. Is that correct?

Comment: I change pic because it was not clear. Now i have in NR .2 B2 2018.09.19 09:21 that is correct this is the start point that i wanted to find closest date before in file NR. 2. So we can see that closest date before is in A3 cell 2018.09.18 17:25. And i wanted to bring value that is by this date in A3 in cell C3 to file NR.2 in F2

Answer (score 0):

An array formula seems to work.  To enter the array formula, type in the formula and then press **Ctrl-Shift-Enter**

Assuming NR.1 is kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx

```
=INDEX('[kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx]Single'!$C:$C;
        MATCH(A2 + B2;
             '[kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx]Single'!$An:$Am +
             '[kontaktų ričių duomenys.xlsx]Single'!$Bn:$Bm;
             1)
       )
```

That formula would be for row 2 in NR.2 
Note that the values for *n* and *m* need to be set to the first and last rows of your lookup array. After further testing, I noticed that using the entire column reference returns incorrect results. So, if your lookup array is in rows 2 to 250, then use $A$2:$A$250 and $B$2:$B$250.